# Build QGIS 2.16.3 on windows 7 SP1 x64

Tags: qgis

I'm  trying to learn how to build QGIS from source perfectly with windows 7 x64 to adapt QGIS for a urban planing. But I get plenty of errors.

Until now this is what I'm doing:

### PART1: VISUAL STUDIO

I download and install Visual C++ 2010 Express from this link:

```
microsoft-visual-cpp-express.soft32.es/descarga-gratuita/?dm=1
```

I download and install Windows SDK 7.1 y NET Framework 4 from this link:

```
filehippo.com/es/download_microsoft_windows_sdk_for_windows_7_and_net_framework_4/
```

### PART2: OTHER DEPENDENCIES AND TOOLS

I download and install CMake 2.8.6 x86: `cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.6-win32-x86.exe`

I download and install these packages from:

```
cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe
```

- flex
- bison
- GIT
- Perl
- Wget
- Unzip
- Tar
- Bzip2

I download and install OSGEO4W with advance install: `download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup-x86.exe`

I look for these package in search, and install them
- expat
- fcgi
- gdal
- gsl
- iconv
- pyqt4
- qca
- json
- qt4
- qwt
- sip
- spatialite
- libspatialindex
- python
- qscintilla

### PART3: PREPARING BATCH FILE

I use this batch file:

```
@echo off

  set VS90COMNTOOLS=%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\

  call "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

  set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include

set LIB=%LIB%;%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib

  set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W

  call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"

  path %PATH%;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\CMake\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

  @set GRASS_PREFIX=c:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-6.4.4

  @set GRASS_PREFIX7=c:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-7.0.4

  @set SIP_BINARY_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/apps/Python27/sip.exe

  @set QWT_LIBRARY=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/lib/qwt.lib

  @set SIP_BINARY_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%/bin/sip.exe

  @set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\include

  @set LIB=%LIB%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib


  @cmd
```

### PART4: CMAKE

I enter `CMD` from the batch file created and I write:

```
cmake-gui
```

I select where the source is,and where to build the binaries

I press configure and i got this log:

> - Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10
> - Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
> - Detecting C compiler ABI info
> - Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> - Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10
> - Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
> - Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> - Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> - QGIS version: 2.16.3 NÃ¸debo (21603)
> - Found GRASS 6: c:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-6.4.4 (6.4.4, off_t size =    )
> - Found GRASS 7: c:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-7.0.4 (7.0.4, off_t size =    8)
> - Found Proj: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/proj.lib
> - Found GEOS: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/geos_c.lib (3.5.0)
> - Found GDAL: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/gdal_i.lib (2.1.1)
> - Found Expat: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/libexpat.lib
> - Found Spatialindex: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialindex_i.lib
> - Found Qwt: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/qwt.lib (6.0.2)
> - Found Sqlite3: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/sqlite3_i.lib
> - Found PostgreSQL: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/libpq.lib
> - Found SpatiaLite: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite.lib
> - Looking for gaiaDropTable in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite.lib
> - Looking for gaiaDropTable in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite.lib - not    found
> - Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite.lib
> - Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite.lib
> - not found
> - Looking for spatialite_init_ex in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite.lib
> - Looking for spatialite_init_ex in C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite.lib - not    found
> - Qt WebKit support enabled
> - Looking for Q_WS_X11
> - Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found.
> - Looking for Q_WS_WIN
> - Looking for Q_WS_WIN - found
> - Looking for Q_WS_QWS
> - Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
> - Looking for Q_WS_MAC
> - Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
> - Found Qt4: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/qmake.exe (found suitable version "4.8.6",    required is "4.8.0")
> - Found Qt version: 4.8.6
> - Touch support disabled
> - Found QScintilla2: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/qscintilla2.lib (2.8.4)
> - Found QCA: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/qca.lib (2.1.0)
> - Pedantic compiler settings enabled
> - Found PythonInterp: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/python.exe (found suitable version    "2.7.4", required is "2.7")
> - Found Python executable: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/python.exe
> - Found Python version: 2.7.4
> - Found Python library: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python27/libs/python27.lib
> - Found PyQt4 version: 4.11.3
> - Found SIP version: 4.16.5
> - Found QScintilla2 PyQt module: 2.8.4
> - Found GSL: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/gsl.lib;C:/OSGeo4W/lib/cblas.lib
> - txt2tags not found - disabled
> - Ctest Binary Directory set to: C:/AGIS/output/bin
> - Configuring done

### PART5: VCEXPRESS

I get these error when i build "ALL-BUILD" after accessing visual studio from cmd "vcexpress":

> 106 Errors:
>
> - qgsaggregatecalulator.cpp Warning C4702: unreachable code
> - qgsqml.cpp  Warning C4389: signed/unsigned mismatch
> - qlist.h Warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
> - qhash.h Warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
> - qvector.h Warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
> - qmap.h Warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
>
> 24064 Warning
>
> - Spatialite.lib
> - qgis_core.dll
> - Microsoft.Common.targets

### PART6: NSIS

If i try to get the binary installer for windows, i get this error when he unpack the downloaded packages:
[image: error]
Please help me to get an installer for windows, my objective is to add custom plugins and QIG template and repack in an windows installer so I can give it to my friends.

Comment: Are you sure you want to build just so you can package QGIS + some plugins?  You could use installer builder software EXE to MSI is on that package the normal installer + anything extra you need.

Comment: i dont want to add plugins only, i want to change everything i can to help the user to design better in QGIS . However i need for that understand well how the building process works, and i prefer to learn for windows if the posibility exist rather that linux

Comment: Are you building for 64 bit or 32? If you're building for 64 then you will need to use OSGEO4W 64 and cywgin 64, not 32.